# functions file changes happened and received syntax error on server side. what can i do next?

Tags: wordpress

What should I do? I'm stuck in this situation. And the Functions.php file didn't open yet. Suggest something Please

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just to clear up some things.

Did you change the file?

Comment: I change in the functions.php file. but after save this refresh the page and got a syntax error. I'm back to the functions.php file for undo, but the file didn't open now. All these changes occur on the server side. so what can I do now?

Comment: You might need FTP Access since the website is not willing to respond. From there you should be able to edit the file back and fix the error

Comment: but from a client site, I didn't get FTP. And now the client is no longer available at that time.

Comment: Well, it will be hard to recover the site without anything else than WP-Admin since you have created a response error. Where do you host your website?

Comment: I have wp-admin access, but after doing changes the wp-admin section didn't opened, is it any solution to find the FTP port,username,password using wp-admin login?

Comment: Look what i just wrote "Where do you host your website?"

Comment: I don't know, client just sent me the username and password of the site and site URL only.

Comment: Well. Unless you can get a connection to the WP-Admin you will need another type of access

Comment: yup you're right, but i guess on that time I don't have another option , just wait for the client response and get FTP access and then doing work.